# The universal installer for ODAC cannot see Visual Studio

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, odac

I just installed Visual Studio Community 2015 on my computer and tried to install ODTwithODAC121021 (32bit). Well, the Oracle universal installer tells me it cannot proceed because I have to install Visual Studio first. Can someone tell me how I can persuade the installer that I do indeed have Visual Studio? I'm running everything on Windows Server 2008 R2 in case that helps and I did not install an Oracle client, since I assume that it is included with the ODAC tools. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to install different / older versions of Visual Studio?

Comment: No.  I will try today. I first wanted to try with the free VS versions, but I've seen in the system requirements that ODAC does not work with VS Express

Comment: I would say the community version does not support it. I tried the community 2013 on a different computer where ODAC apparently installs but, when I try to open an oracle connection from visual studio, the oracle data provider is nowhere visible. However, I installed the professional edition (2013) and everything works

Answer (score 0):

The current version of ODT doesn't support Visual Studio 2015.
[They will support it after 1 month of VS 2015 RTM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's now supported, as of 05 October :)

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index.html

Comment: I just tried and it is correct. However, I just took the executable developed on  a different machine with a different version of the Oracle data provider and, when I run it on the machine where I installed the last version, it tells me that it can't find the data access provider. Where is the versioning info in the source code? In the App.config? In the .xml? In the assembly references? Thanks in advance.